# Sort xdebug output

Tags: linux, sorting, xdebug

I have a xdebug function trace output that looks like this:

```
 1130.8156  482236096     -160               -> memory_get_usage()
 1130.8156  482236112      +16               -> X
 1130.8157  482236112       +0                 -> Y
 1130.8157  482236328     +216                 -> Z
 1130.8157  482236200     -128               -> X
 1130.8157  482236280      +80                 -> X
 1130.8157  482236360      +80                   -> X
 1130.8157  482236440      +80                     -> X
 1130.8158  482237488    +1048                     -> X
```

I want to sort by the third column (-160,-128,0 ...)

```
sort -n -k3
```

is not working.

Comment: Looks like I have to use the -g option:

    sort -k3 -g test.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I have to use the -g option: `sort -k3 -g test.txt`